# Iterate VLOOKUP on a column

Tags: excel, formula, libreoffice, vlookup

On LibreOffice (same on Excel?), I'd like to iterate the formula VLOOKUP(C2;B1:D2;3;0) to all my column. e.g. VLOOKUP(C2;B1:D2;3;0), VLOOKUP(C3;B1:D3;3;0), VLOOKUP(C4;B1:D4;3;0), etc

But if I copy-paste, I get VLOOKUP(C3;B2:D3;3;0), VLOOKUP(C4;B3:D4;3;0), etc --> the array is always the same size

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the formula, you should put a dollar sign before the row number (or column letter) that you want to stay fixed when the formula is pasted elsewhere. This makes an absolute reference (as opposed to relative references).

So, your formula should look like this: `VLOOKUP(C2;B$1:D2;3;0)`.